# Running a process builder at a specific time

Tags: email, batch, process-builder, apex-email-service, email-alert

I have a requirement to send email notification at specific time. In salesforce I have a list of employees stored in there. I would like to have an option to send email to all the employees who have a specific status field value = 'active'.

I would like to have the capability to specify the time when the emails should triggered to all the employees with active status.(I have a process builder set up which send out email alerts).

In a gist- I would like to send out mass email to all the employee stored in Salesforce at a specific time mentioned by the admin. There are about more than 10,000 employees in salesforce and all are outside of salesforce. May be not use process builder and send email alert using single or mass email messaging. But I think there is a limit of 1000 on these and I have more than 10,000 employees to whom I have to send email alerts. Correct me if I am wrong.

What can be the best way to achieve this. Is there any appexchange app which can support this functionality?

Comment: All at the same time? Variable schedule? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I would like to send out mass email alert to all the employee stored in Salesforce at a specific time mentioned by the admin.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. All at the same time? Do you plan to tweak it frequently?

Comment: Oh.. the purpose is to send email to each employee. It can be in the same day not specifically in the same time. So if I say send email alert at 12 pm then the email can be sent with in 24 hrs period from 12 pm. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) allows you to set recurrent date/time to run your code. You can then use the [Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) class to send out emails. If it is just a one-time email you can request support to temporarily increase your limit. If not, I would advise the best solution would be to use a third-party email service.

Comment: I heard it's not easy to increase the Messaging email limit as you need to have a strong justification for that. I am think to write a schedule job which runs a batch. This batch just updates the records in Salesforce which will trigger the process builder and it will send out an email. As with process builder the email limit is 1000 * # licenses. I have enough licenses to handle this. I was think if Conga Composer can make things easier?

Comment: I have combined apex and process builder in the past and it works most of the time but not good when it comes to error handling.

Comment: I think you will have to use Conga Conductor for scheduling, just checked and saw that Conga uses SendGrid to send emails. Cost wise it would be better to use a third-party service directly depending on your volume and frequency. https://sendgrid.com/blog/conga-composer-empowers-email-deliverability-for-salesforce-users-with-sendgrid/

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using Apex. I need a functionality in such a way that a user can specify the email template and time in which those template can be sent to the Employee's email id(external email ids). The user can send various templates in different times. It should be dynamic. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! The process builder would not work if the template is going to be dynamic. Perhaps a visualforce page for the user to specify template and time, and scheduled apex to send emails in batches? But it's not going to be easy and will involve a good amount of development time. Do let us know your final solution!

Comment: Using visualforce page and giving user the ability to select time and template to send emails - I guess in this approach i would hit daily email limit of 1000 as I might have to send email to around 10,000 employees of my company. And yes this would take a while to be build even if I request salesforce to increase my daily email limits. Wondering if this can be achieved by any 3rd party app like Mass mailer.